# Sharing test data across xUnit Theory tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have an api with a 'listing' method that supports some filtering capability.  I wanted to write an integration test in xUnit that setup the data once in the database, then run several different iterations of filtering against the data.

Below is *not* correct as it runs the test method for each `InlineData` and populates the database.

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData( "File_1_CE.xlsm", 1 )]
[InlineData( "File_1_CE", 2 )]
public async Task GetListing_WithNameFilters_ReturnsCorrectResults( string name, int expected )
{
    // Arrange
    // Want to create some data that is shared across all InlineData (or TheoryData<T>) runs...
    await factory.FooBarCreateListingTestData();

    using var client = factory.CreateClient();

    // Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync( Contracts.V1.ApiEndpoints.CalcEngines.Build.Listing( new [] { name } ) );
    var result = ( await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Contracts.V1.Responses.ListResult<Contracts.V1.Responses.ManagedFileInfo>>() )!;

    // Assert - Response has single result
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be( HttpStatusCode.OK );
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    result.Total.Should().Be( check.Expected );
    result.Items.Should().HaveCount( expected );
}
```

If I wanted to use a [Theory] pattern, I believe my only options are:

1. In the test, use a `try/finally` to create the data each time and in the `finally` destroy the data.
2. Create a separate class for just my 'listing test' and use the `IClassFixture<T>` pattern and populate the database in the `InitializeAsync` method and destroy it in the `DisposeAsync` method.

I don't like option 1 because I was trying to eliminate the overhead of creating and destroying data in the database for every theory run.  I don't like option 2 because I wanted to group all my 'Get' method tests in a single class (as is common practice my many - especially those on my team) and I didn't want to make a separate class just for the `GetListing` method.

But maybe these are my only options?

Comment: Ideally one would abstract out the database and mock the data provider (or use an in-memory database) to reduce the overhead of recreating the data. Working with fresh-data-per-test-case is preferable. But I guess we don't live in an ideal world. And unfortunately the way to context-share in xUnit is through [Class/Collection/Assembly Fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context).

Comment: its a question of whether they can share the data, and whether they can run concurrently.
a CollectionFixture will let you have single spin up/tear down, and will restrict to one running at a time
a ClassFixture will let you run/build one at a time per test class
or you can manually create an IDisposable and tear it down via `using` in the context of your test run. If you are not doing a collection fixture, you'd have each constructon of the fixture trigger the initalizaion if you're going from 0 to 1.